# DCount vs. SQL SELECT COUNT(*)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

I am trying to get a count of all items sent to a supplier based on the purchase order they are assigned to.  But I can't seem to get the control to show a number of items based on the purchase order instance - it keeps throwing either a #name? or #error! message in the text box when the form is activated.

Create statement for tblPODetail

```
USE [instkeeper_test]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPODetail](
    [intPurchaseOrderInstance] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [intPONumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [datDateEntered] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [bolPOOpen] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [intRMANumber] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [strSupplierCode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [strSupplierLastAddress] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [strSupplierLastCity] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [strSupplierLastState] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [strSupplierLastPostalCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [strSupplierLastCountry] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [strSupplierLastPhone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [strSupplierLastFax] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [datDateSent] [datetime] NULL,
    [datDateReceived] [datetime] NULL,
    [bolAdvGageTrakNoTouch] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [bolAdvHardCopies] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [bolFreightShip] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [bolReturnableUsed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [bolInHouse] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [strUPSTrackNumOut] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [strFedExTrackNumOut] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [strFreightTrackNumOut] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [strUPSTrackNumIn] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [strFedExTrackNumIn] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [strFreightTrackNumIn] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SSMA_TimeStamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPODetail]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$tblPODetail$strSupplierCode$disallow_zero_length] CHECK  ((len([strSupplierCode])>(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPODetail] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$tblPODetail$strSupplierCode$disallow_zero_length]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPODetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__tblPODeta__intPO__6C190EBB]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [intPONumber]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPODetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__tblPODeta__datDa__6D0D32F4]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [datDateEntered]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPODetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__tblPODeta__bolPO__6E01572D]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [bolPOOpen]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPODetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__tblPODeta__bolAd__6EF57B66]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [bolAdvGageTrakNoTouch]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPODetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__tblPODeta__bolAd__6FE99F9F]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [bolAdvHardCopies]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPODetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__tblPODeta__bolFr__70DDC3D8]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolFreightShip]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPODetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__tblPODeta__bolRe__71D1E811]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolReturnableUsed]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPODetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__tblPODeta__bolIn__72C60C4A]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolInHouse]
GO
```

Create statement for tblPOGaugeDetail

```
USE [instkeeper_test]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPOGaugeDetail](
    [intItemPOID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [intGagePOID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [strGageDetailID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [datGageSent] [datetime] NULL,
    [datGageReceived] [datetime] NULL,
    [bolGageCalibrate] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [bolGageRepair] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [bolGageEvaluate] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [bolGageAccredited] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [bolGageReturned] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [bolGageException] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [bolGageExceptResolved] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [bolGageLeavePriceBlank] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [intGageCost] [real] NULL,
    [intTurnaroundDaysOut] [int] NULL,
    [SSMA_TimeStamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [tblPOGaugeDetail$PrimaryKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [intItemPOID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPOGaugeDetail]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [tblPOGaugeDetail$tblPODetailtblPOGaugeDetail] FOREIGN KEY([intGagePOID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblPODetail] ([intPurchaseOrderInstance])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPOGaugeDetail] CHECK CONSTRAINT [tblPOGaugeDetail$tblPODetailtblPOGaugeDetail]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPOGaugeDetail] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [intGagePOID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPOGaugeDetail] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [bolGageCalibrate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPOGaugeDetail] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolGageRepair]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPOGaugeDetail] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolGageEvaluate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPOGaugeDetail] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolGageAccredited]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPOGaugeDetail] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolGageReturned]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPOGaugeDetail] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolGageException]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPOGaugeDetail] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolGageExceptResolved]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPOGaugeDetail] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolGageLeavePriceBlank]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPOGaugeDetail] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [intGageCost]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPOGaugeDetail] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [intTurnaroundDaysOut]
GO
```

Query statement for purchase order details that I want the counts to appear in

```
SELECT dbo_tblPODetail.intPurchaseOrderInstance, dbo_tblPODetail.strSupplierCode, dbo_tblPODetail.bolPOOpen, dbo_tblPODetail.intPONumber, dbo_tblPODetail.datDateSent
FROM dbo_tblPODetail
WHERE (((dbo_tblPODetail.bolPOOpen)=True))
ORDER BY dbo_tblPODetail.datDateSent;
```

I've been a bit frustrated as I've read a bit on both DCount() and SELECT COUNT(*), but can't seem to get -either- of them to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

-- Edited 06/18/2009 @ 1542 hours --

This is an example of the SELECT COUNT I tried to use in code when the subform's On Current event triggered:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ItemsSent 
FROM [dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail] 
WHERE [dbo_tblPOGageDetail]![intGagePOID] = [dbo_tblPODetail]![intPurchaseOrderInstance]
```

This is an example of the =DCOUNT statement as attached to the control in the subform.

```
=DCOUNT("*", "[dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail]", "[intGagePOID] = [Forms]![frmSupplierInfoMain]![subfrmOpenPOBySupplierID]![intPurchaseOrderInstance]")
```

Neither of these worked - sadly.

Comment: Could you show us the select count that you are trying to execute?

Comment: I'm assuming that when you manually run that select query that it works. How are you getting the result into the TextBox?

Comment: After running the SQL SELECT COUNT(*) statement, I would pull it as a recordset, setting the control's value to that DAO recordset value.  It didn't work though, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your query work without the count(*)?

Use an actual field name for the first arguement of DCount
Get the control name out of the where string.

```
For DCOUNT("[intItemPOID],"[dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail]","[intGagePOID]=" & Forms]![frmSupplierInfoMain]![subfrmOpenPOBySupplierID]![intPurchaseOrderInstance])
```

Comment: It was my understanding (which could definitely be flawed) that I could only reference field names from the domain (table) on which the DCount was being used - in this case dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.  Can I really use the intPuchaseOrderInstance field from the dbo_tblPODetail table on which the original query is pulling from?

Comment: I get a #Name? when I try the following DCount in the control source on the subform:

    =DCount([dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail]![intItemPOID],[dbo_tblPOGageDetail],[dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail]![intGagePOID]=[dbo_tblPODetail]![intPurchaseOrderInstance])

Comment: DCount is like SQL:
"Field_Name", "Table_Name", "field_name = 'G'"
You want strings and not objects on your form (Unless they are a string value equal to a name of a field,table, criteria.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I found that the problem was in the spelling that Access was using for one of the table names when using the expression builder.  It was misspelled there, but not anywhere else - if I wrote it in manually, it worked, if I used the expression builder - it would bomb out.  Thank you everyone for the help.  :)